# How do you create a checksum in Maven then output it to a text file?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, checksum

Still learning how to use `Maven`, and I was wondering if there is a way to do a `checksum` on the generated `WAR` file.

The `Maven` goal is `package`, and what I'm trying to achieve is to get a `checksum` value (of the packaged `WAR` file) put into a text file alongside the packaged file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The following plugins might be what you may be looking for: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/installing-checksums.html http://nicoulaj.github.io/checksum-maven-plugin/examples/generating-project-artifacts-checksums.html

Comment: What is the purpose of that? Why do you need such checksum ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Using `Bamboo` and the checksum is going to be used for bug tracking system

Comment: The checksum is used for bug tracking? Sounds strange. The revision of the version control (sha1 for git or revision for svn) is the correct relationship for bug tracking system or the log messages which contain references to a issue tracking systems.

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry, my mistake. We are using something for bug tracking and the checksum, which I'm trying to generate, will be to check if the code has changed from a previous state or not.

Comment: Why not using your version control system which makes more sense and exists already. Don't reinvent the wheel. Furthermore what about a continious integration solution like Jenkins (ok ok you use bamboo and paying money).

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using svn, but the reason for the checksum is so that that someone who doesn't have access to the source code can see if the packaged file has changed.

Comment: Why would like to know someone who has no svn access if something has changed? Does not make sense from my point of view. Furthermore based on not changing the files in svn and simply making a rebuild will also change the checksums so the result is useless.

Comment: @khmarbaise a good checksum will not change is nothing changes or if everything becomes the same as it use to be. We are using the checksum because bamboo is packaging the the project everyday. The client will be downloading the war file from bamboo but not have access to the svn. If the checksum value is the same as the current one they have there is no need for them to get the new file.

Comment: If the client is the consumer i would prever using the artifact version for such purposes cause it sound like a delivery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working with the below `pom` code and changing my `Maven` goal to `verify`

```
<dependency>
    ...
    <!-- CheckSum -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.ju-n.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.51</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.ju-n.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>artifacts</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                    <includes>
                      <include>**/*.war</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
            <csvSummary>true</csvSummary>
            <csvSummaryFile>IRIDDS-checksums.csv</csvSummaryFile>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                <version>1.51</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```