# Maven, save checksum files in target(build) directory

Tags: maven, checksum

I'm using *maven-install-plugin* to generate checksum of my .war files, but they are saved in my local maven repo.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <createChecksum>true</createChecksum>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

What I need:

1) Save checksum files in my target build directory instead.

2) Copy generated checksum files from target build directory to another location (using *maven-dependency-plugin* ?).

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar - here's how I am doing it currently:

To generate the checksums, I am using the *checksum-maven-plugin*.
Here is a pom.xml snippet which will generate .sha1 checksum files in your target/ directory for all the .war files it finds there.
You can tweak the `<includes/>` spec to change which files get checksummed, and you can tweak the `<algorithms/>` spec to specify which checksum algorithms are used.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>net.ju-n.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>checksum-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>checksum-maven-plugin-files</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>files</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
          <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>*.war</include>
          </includes>
        </fileSet>
      </fileSets>
      <algorithms>
        <algorithm>SHA-1</algorithm>
      </algorithms>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

The copying of the generated checksums from target directory to another location can be done several ways, and I think I need a bit more information on your usage to recommend a solution - can you give more details on how you are planning to use the checksum files and where they go in your build hierarchy?

References:

http://nicoulaj.github.io/checksum-maven-plugin/

[How do you create a checksum in Maven then output it to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368728/how-do-you-create-a-checksum-in-maven-then-output-it-to-a-text-file?rq=1)